# Serverless: dynamodb giving error on create record when trying with async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

I am trying to create a record in dynamodb(Using dynamoose). code is

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.table = dynamoose.model(tableName, tableSchema);
  }
//  userdata object - { 
//  cusotmerEmail: 'tushar.gaurav+testf40@accionlabs.com',
//  customerBusinessName: 'DoogleDnd',
//  customerFirstName: 'Tushar',
//  customerId: 101211,
//  customerLastName: 'Gaurav',
//  isDeleted: false,
//  sku: '100',
//  userId: '5c1776e94bea867c3f896236' 
// }


  async createUser(userData) {
    try {
      const res = await this.table.create(userData);
      console.log('Update user record - ', res);
      return res;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

*input values to the create function are correct as the same input I tried with **batchPut()**, it's working.
And even update call to the table is also working.

```
async updateUser(userData) {
    try {
      const res = await this.table.update(userData);
      console.log('Updated user record - ', res);
      return res;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
 }
```

This is the error I am getting - 
**Error -  {"message":"The conditional request failed", "code":"ConditionalCheckFailedException", "statusCode":400}**

This is the calling function -

```
module.exports.subscribeUser = async (event) => {
  let inputBody = (typeof event.body === 'object' ? event.body : 
  JSON.parse(event.body));
  inputBody.userId = event.pathParameters.id;
  try {
    // Validate input
    await asisvc.validateInput(inputBody);

    inputBody = await UserSvc.constructUserObject(inputBody);
    console.log('Constructed object - ', JSON.stringify(inputBody));

    const userData = await testObj.createUser(inputBody);
    return Utils.buildResp(codes.ok, { userData }, {});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return Utils.buildResp(codes.badrequest, { Error: 
Utils.getErrString(error) }, {});
```

}
};

I tried googling it, but didn't find any proper document. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also show the code where you call these functions and write what is the expected output and what actually happens?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you do know that a) there's no benefit to catching and re-throwing your error if you don't actually do anything else with it, and b) the Error constructor takes a string message as its first parameter, not an object.

Comment: Also, what actual error did you get?

Comment: @libik Edited the question, Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

In Dynamoose by default we check to see if the primary key already exists in the table when using the `Model.create` method.

So your error:

```
{"message":"The conditional request failed", "code":"ConditionalCheckFailedException", "statusCode":400}
```

Indicates that the primary key already exists in the table. So you are trying to create a duplicate item.

In the [documentation](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#modelcreateobject-options-callback) there is an options property that you can use to allow overriding the object.

For example the following code will allow overrides:

```
const res = await this.table.create(userData, {overwrite: true});
```